# Cannot reach default unsubscribe / profile center or any landing page created in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

we cannot access the landing pages and default unusbscribe/profile center in Marketing Cloud. We're keep getting an error message from the browser saying "This site can't be reached - click.company-country.com's server IP address could not be found... DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN". I've tried logging in from different computers, different networks and devices, but keep having the same error message. What could be the case here?

Comment: no idea what this is, but maybe start with checking the status of the stack you are on.. https://status.salesforce.com/products/Marketing_Cloud/instances

Comment: Did you DNS record get changed?

Comment: Have you initiated SSL provisioning? We have this sort of situation with a customer where the process has been started and as soon as some switch is set by salesforce all http(s) reliant features are impacted until the configuration is complete. Note that this also affects email tracking and the view email in browser URL.